# Inject dependency on Session_End event

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, global-asax

I'm trying to inject a dependency on the Session_End event in `Global.asax.cs` but when it gets fired it will throw a NullReferenceException, this is my code:

```
//This works
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var accessLogger = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAccessLogger>();
}
//This does NOT work
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var accessLogger = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAccessLogger>();
}
```

Comment: Please post a stack trace. What object is null? `DependencyResolver.Current`?

Comment: Does the `DependencyResolver.Current` property rely on `HttpContext.Current`? There won't be a current context in the `Session_End` event, as it will fire 20 minutes after the user's last request.

Comment: `DependencyResolver.Current` is a static property that not magically returns `null` after it has been set. Are you sure that `Sessen_End` event gets called in the same app domain?